# Can't connect media devices to computer (Canon Camera, Cell Phone)

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have installed Windows 7 on my Lenovo Ideapad u310 and I am not able to connect (almost) any disk devices to my computer. For example, when plugging in my Canon 7D camera it shows up as a Canon Camera but Windows update fails to find drivers. I have checked Canon's homepage from drivers and installed their utility program but still can't connect my camera.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more information. Otherwise it will be very hard to answer this question. Also: start with a simple USB flash disk instead of a Camera. It will make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: USB flash disks worked, but media devices don't. What I have tried that does not work are cameras and tablets.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Turned out I had installed Windows 7 N, which apparently doesn't not have the media drivers needed (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/what-is-windows-7-n-edition). Its really strange that it can't find the drivers though Windows Update.

The solution was to install the "Windows Media Feature Pack" (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546).

Now everything works.